# Trial of Artifactory Pro won't start up due to "No valid installed license found. Blocking conversion" error

Tags: artifactory

I am currently trying to upgrade 6.19.0 OSS/Community Edition to 7.38.10 Pro but receive the following error in the console.log file during startup and the services don't start:

```
2022-06-08T08:49:23.113Z ^[[1;32m[jfrt ]^[[0;39m ^[[31m[WARN ]^[[0;39m [d45022dae25fb651] [o.a.a.ConverterBlockerImpl:72 ] [Catalina-utility-1  ] - No valid installed license found. Blocking conversion
2022-06-08T08:49:23.115Z ^[[1;32m[jfrt ]^[[0;39m ^[[1;31m[ERROR]^[[0;39m [d45022dae25fb651] [d.c.m.ConverterManagerImpl:277] [Catalina-utility-1  ] - Conversion failed. You should analyze the error and retry launching Artifactory. Error is: Converter can't run since no matching license found, please add new license
```

I have added a file jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/artifactory.lic with the trial license but that doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: in which version did you added this trial license, is it 6.19 or 7.38? Also,what are the permissions given to jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/artifactory.lic file and is the trial license correctly added?

Comment: I have tried it with both versions. Currently back to trying with 7.38.10 Pro. I have also tried an upgrade and a fresh install. The permissions on the license file is 644.